# Arabic language is not supported in CentOS

Tags: php, linux, unicode, centos, arabic

I am not able to save Arabic text when I moved my project to a new server (CentOS 6). The coding and database structure are the same. But in my new server it is printing just like `????`.

I checked the `php.ini` and found that `mbstring` is installed.

[image]

Please, Anybody tell me if anything else need to be in the server for supporting Arabic language.

Comment: How did you move the project? Maybe it's the database that's the problem? You have to follow the trail and figure out which component is broken.

Comment: just download files from one server and uploaded to the new server. Exported the db and imported to the new one

Comment: Did you export in UTF-8 and import also in UTF-8? Are the database settings all set to use UTF-8 on the new server?

Comment: yes am having all the Arabic values in db. But when i update it from my edit form the corresponding text changed to "???"

Answer (score 0):

All table collation was correct. But the problem was *database collation*. It is not changed to `utf8_general_ci`. The issue solved when I changed the collation from `latin1_general_ci` to `utf8_general_ci`.